# Getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java

I am able to compile code but while running it is throughing classnotfound

`C:\Users\Desktop\New>javac -classpath java-mail-1.4.4.jar SendMail.java`

`C:\Users\Desktop\New>java -classpath java-mail-1.4.4.jar SendMail`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: SendMail
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SendMail
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: SendMail.  Program will exit.
```

Can you suggest how to solve this?

Comment: does the `SendMail.class` exist in the `C:\Users\Desktop\New` path ?

Comment: mail.jar missing in your class path.

Comment: @VaibhavJain no then it would have thrown `java.lang.ClassNotFound` exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

**Windows**

```
java -classpath java-mail-1.4.4.jar;. SendMail
                    note this  ----^
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using below commands

To compile java class

`javac -classpath .;<jar file path>;  Abc.java`

To execute java class

`java -classpath .;<jar file path>; Abc`